# Reverse Mutable List Ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml, mutable

I need to write a function that takes two mutable lists as input and as an output has the first list reversed appended to the second list. The type definition is:

```
type 'a mylist = 'a listcell ref
  and 'a listcell = Nil | Cons of 'a * ('a mylist)
```

I am aware how to reverse a regular list but am having some confusion on writing a function that does this by destructively changing the first list.
Here is what I have but I keep getting a type error:

```
let rec rev_app l1 l2 =
  let rec rev_app' l3 l4 =
    match !l1 with
    | Nil -> l2
    | Cons (x,t) -> ref (rev_app t (Cons(x,l4)))
  in rev_app' l1 l2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner call to is to `rev_app`, not to `rev_app'`. So your code is somewhat similar to saying:

```
let rec f x = ref (f x)
```

As a side comment, it is good manners to quote the actual error you're getting. Just saying "a type error" isn't so helpful.